# OpenGL Texture Buffer - GLSL Syntax

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, batch-processing

Assuming I only want to render quads and can reuse my mesh, I would like to be able to, in a single draw call, render many instances.

I would like to achieve this with a texture buffer object by placing transformation matrices into the buffer.

I understand how to setup a texture buffer object in C++, but am confused on how to grab my transformations from this in GLSL.

```
uniform samplerBuffer sampler;
...
... = texelFetch( sampler, index );
```

In the above code (in a vertex shader) I'm not sure how the `samplerBuffer` keyword works (and have had a lot of trouble finding documentation). I would like to know which index in the texture buffer a given vertex is associated with, this way a transformation lookup can occur. How can I do this, and what would the GLSL syntax look like?

It can be assumed that the transformation matrices are 4x4 matrices. I was hoping to be able to keep the OpenGL version requirements in the 2.XX range.

Edit: So I found this: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_instanced.txt. I can deal with a 3.0 limitation. However I'm getting confused when looking up examples of how to use this. Using GLEW, I suppose I would call glDrawElementsInstanced, but some places on the internet are saying this requires OpenGL version 3.3 or later. How can I take advantage of the 3.0 requirement I linked?

Comment: You can also use Uniform buffers which are much more suitable for multiple  vector and matrix blocks upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a buffer texture is essentially a 1D array of data stored in a buffer object's (`TEXTURE_BUFFER`) data store. You provide a single integer, which is essentially an offset into the buffer and fetch a single texel with `texelFetch` starting at that offset. The offset always refers to a texel, not to a single component (e.g. the `R`-component of a `vec4`) of a texel. Therefore, if you setup the buffer texture with an internal format `GL_R`, you'll look up a single texel which only stores a single value - however, if you're using `GL_RGBA` a texel will consist of four components.

For instance, suppose you choose to put two normalized color vectors with `RGBA` components into the data store, choose the internal format `GL_RGBA` and index with 0 and 1, you'll get the first and the second texel from the buffer texture, as per **section 8.9** of the **core OpenGL 4.4 spec**:

> [..]the attached buffer object’s data store is interpreted as an array of elements of the GL data type corresponding to *internalformat*. Each texel consists of one to four elements that are mapped to texture components (R, G, B, and A).

Note that `texelFetch` will *always* return a `gvec4`, that is, an `ivec4`, `uivec4` or `vec4` depending on the internal format. If you choose an internal format which specifies less than four components, for instance `GL_R32F`, the result will be an *unnormalized* (<- that's important!) `vec4(R, 0, 0, 1)` - the remaining `GB` components are set to zero and `A` to 1. See **table 8.15** of the aforementioned spec for a complete overview.

Also note that `texelFetch` does not perform any filtering or LOD clamping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I also made a minor edit to my question at the bottom, perhaps you could help with this? I'm just confused as to version requirements.

Comment: Instanced rendering became core in GL 3.1, so anything concerning that functionality, including corresponding draw calls, are to be supported by a GL 3.1 conformant implementation. If you're stuck with GL 3.0, you can still check if `GL_ARB_draw_instanced` is available and simply use the ARB version. If you want to know for sure what's new in a GL version, check the appropriate appendix - for GL3 it's appendices F through I in the core GL 3.3 spec.

Answer (score 2):

All versions of [texelFetch](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/texelFetch.xml) returns gvec4 so I assume you should perform a 4 lookups, 1 for each row. But that depends on how you encoded your matrix.

```
uniform samplerBuffer sampler;
...
mat4 transform( texelFetch( sampler, RowIndex0 ), texelFetch( sampler, RowIndex1 ), texelFetch( sampler, RowIndex2 ), texelFetch( sampler, RowIndex3 ) );
```

Keep in mind that `mat4` in GLSL takes columns in the constructor, so you need to transpose that if you are working with Column based matrices.